# How to handle doubleclick event on Textfield with vaadin

Tags: mouseevent, textfield, vaadin

Using Vaadin, I have a Form with some TextField, I want handle event based on doubleclick into the textfield (copy text from one to another).

There is no example of such handling.

Is that possible ? and if yes how ?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question. There is a sample in the vaadin sampler showing how vaadin can handle it

http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#ClickableLayoutBasic

It shows various Field included TextField reacting to mouse events.

Comment: This example did not work within a form. When textfields is inside a form no event is captured . Any ideas ?

Comment: This is a bug http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/6346.
"LayoutClickListener doesn't work in FormLayout"